# Google PageSpeed, optimizing Google's own elements

Tags: google, google-analytics, cache, page-speed, fonts

I'm trying Google's PageSpeed online service

Ironically, it's primarily highlighting Google's own services as something that needs improvement on my site

**1) jQuery from Google**: *blocking*. So I moved all javascript from `<head>` to the end of the document before `</body>`. That helped

**2) Linking to external Google Font CSS** (in `<head>`): *blocking*. But the font is critical to the design of the page and should load before much else

**3) Google Analytics**: *Caching is not good*. (Google has set it internally to 2 hours expiration). Don't know how to change this (this is also placed at the bottom of page)

The Google Font is highlighted as a big priority to change.

How can I fix this? Where/how should I call the the font?

Answer (score 5):

You don't *have* to do *everything* listed as an optimization. If using a custom font is important to the design of your website *then use it*. You have a choice between a slightly slower (initial) page load and a better design versus a slightly faster (initial) page load and a slightly lesser design. If using that font improves your business somehow than it's worth using.

This is no different than the trade off between security and usability. They are always at odds and it must be decided just how secure a site needs to be with an acceptable level of usability.

There's no perfect website that is 100% secure and 100% usable. There is also no perfect website that is super fast and 100% optimized for business results. Find the balance that is right *for your website* and go with it.

Comment: I see what you mean. But it looks like I CAN optimize it some more, I just don't know how exactly. The font is important. But if I can move it to a better location that would be fine too (I'm already relying on Google to supply the font, so why not)

Comment: I don't see how you can optimize it and still use it. The linking to an external font is slow because you are linking to an external font. It must be downloaded to be used and will be slow no matter what you do. The optimization is not to use it.

Comment: Hm yes ok. Perhaps I listen to Google too much ;) But they marked it as an IMPORTANT issue to be fixed.. their own product. Strange

Comment: I do not place too much emphasis on Google's scores or important or non-important rankings.  The real question is does implementing their recommendations improve start-render and page-complete times.  If not, then you are chasing phantoms.  I've seen cases were applying their recommendations actually decreased site performance, so be sure to measure properly using browser based testing.