# How to allow Google fonts to be cached for more than one day?

Tags: htaccess, cache, cache-control

I tried this code below, but I still see the message on Google Insights that the fonts have a expiration of 1d.

```
AddType application/vnd.ms-fontobject .eot 
AddType application/x-font-ttf .ttf
AddType application/x-font-opentype .otf
AddType application/x-font-woff .woff
AddType image/svg+xml .svg

ExpiresActive on

ExpiresByType application/vnd.ms-fontobject "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType application/x-font-ttf "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType application/x-font-opentype "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType application/x-font-woff "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/svg+xml "access plus 1 year"
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google PageSpeed, optimizing Google's own elements](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/68458/google-pagespeed-optimizing-googles-own-elements)

Comment: Unless you upload the fonts to your own server (which would negate the benefits of Google's CDN) then you have no control over resources _external_ to your website. See also [Cache external static scripts](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/16534/cache-external-static-scripts)